# Azure Blob Storage Got 403 Error Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently doing burst activities of SAS URL to upload, download, and delete blobs from Azure but some of the URLs return 403 Error

> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I have created the correct SAS and execute the URL but still not sure how to fix it as I generate the URL something like this

> https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/dBaNbbdPUt_k01?sig=R9qhdgLYwpkzyumbo1d3P3DSG3VzmJSSNKGPRE9b0c0%3D&st=2020-07-31T12%3A35%3A04Z&se=2020-07-31T13%3A35%3A04Z&sv=2019-02-02&sp=r&sr=b

Here are my example codes to generate SAS URL for upload and execute it:

```
public static URL generateUploadSignedURL(String filename, String userId) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, InvalidKeyException, MalformedURLException {
        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobAdmin.getContainerReference(bucketData);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(filename);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();

        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        sasPolicy.setSharedAccessStartTime(Date.from(instant));
        sasPolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(Date.from(instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))); // Use the start time delta one hour as the end time for the shared

        sasPolicy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(
                SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE)
        );

    String token = blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy, null);
    String url = blob.getUri()+"?"+token;
    System.out.println(blob.getUri()+"?"+token);
    return new URL(url);
}

public static int uploadFileWithUrl(InputStream inputStream, URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    if (url.toString().contains("blob.core.windows.net")) { // for azure urls add request property
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
    }
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Multi-Cloud-Management-SignedURL");

    File tempFile = new File("src/main/resources/input.tmp");
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, tempFile);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tempFile.toURI())));
    out.close();

    connection.getResponseCode();
    //System.out.println("HTTP response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());

    connection.disconnect();
    tempFile.delete();

    return connection.getResponseCode();
}
```

Comment: Your SAS has `read` permission (`sp=r`).

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS its only an example of the SAS urls generated using the example code as reference only

Comment: Can you read the response message (I think you will need to use `getResponseMessage()`) and share that? You should see more details about the 403 error.

Comment: Can you share the detailed error as @Stopped suggested?

Comment: @AllenWu The error message that I got  unfortunately is only "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature." as I already wrote in the post